# Is there another way to checking collision without FlxG.collide?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm making a game with Haxe and the HaxeFlixel game engine, and I'm implementing collisions.

I found a way to check for collisions in the [HaxeFlixel cheat sheet](http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/cheat-sheet/):

```
FlxG.overlap(ObjectOrGroup1, ObjectOrGroup2, myCallback);

private function myCallback(Object1:FlxObject, Object2:FlxObject):Void
{
}
```

But I don't like this style because the callback is separated from the function call. I would prefer this:

```
FlxG.overlap(ObjectOrGroup1, ObjectOrgroup2, function() {
    //do something
});
```

I saw this style in JavaScript, but I don't know exactly what it is. Is this possible in Haxe?

And I need this code like this:

```
if (FlxG.collide(Object1, Object2)) {
    //do something
}
```

It must return the value (`true` or `false`) and it processed by if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet for the *anonymous function* is almost correct, but the callback function for [`FlxG.overlap()`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxG.html?#overlap) expects two arguments (the objects that collided). Try this:

```
FlxG.overlap(ObjectOrGroup1, ObjectOrGroup2, function(object1:FlxObject, object2:FlxObject) {
    // do something with object1 and object2
});
```